# How to define name for slug?

Tags: php, laravel

Look at my codes.

web.php

```
Route::get('/{pageSlug}', 'PageController@about')->name('about');
```

RouteServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    Route::bind('pageSlug', function ($value) {
        return Page::whereSlug($value)->firstOrFail();
    });
    parent::boot();
}
```

blade

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('about') }}">About</a>
```

I see this error

> Missing required parameters for [Route: about] [URI: pageSlug}]. (View: C:\xampp3\htdocs\projects\resources\views\Home\layouts\header.blade.

Comment: Just to be sure: "about" is not your page slug? because in that case the whole route config is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the route parameter optional like this:

```
Route::get('/{pageSlug?}', 'PageController@about')->name('about');
```

If it is not optional, you always need to add the parameter when calling the route.

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('about', ['pageSlug' => 'some-slug']) }}">About</a>
```